# How do I know which sides of a triangle are proportional in similar triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, intuition

Please refer to [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPhGY.png) for the diagram.

So I know $\triangle ACE$ is similar to $\triangle BCD$. This is because $\angle BDC=\angle CAE=90^\circ$ and $\angle BCD$ is common to both triangles.

However, how do I know which sides are proportional to each other just by looking?

I am a bit confused here. Is $CD$ proportional to $AE$ or $BD$ proportional to $AE$? The only thing I can deduce is $BC$ is proportional to $EC$ since they are the hypotenuse. So, I get the following:

$\frac{BD}{AE}=\frac{CD}{AC}=\frac{BC}{EC}$ or $\frac{BD}{AC}=\frac{CD}{AE}=\frac{BC}{EC}$

Which one's correct and how can I prove that? Also, how can you tell which sides are proportional to each other in more complex triangles if you know they are similar?

Comment: BD is proportional to AE because they’re both opposite angle BCD. If two triangles are similar, the sides opposite of equal angles are proportional. As for how to prove that in Euclidean geometry, I don’t know.

Comment: Hint: what do you know about the angles of similar triangles?

Comment: Okay so the sides opposite to same angles are proportional. This makes sense to me. Thank you for clearing it out!

Comment: No $2$-or-more Pythagorean triples have the same sine etc. unless they are similar because all primitives and their multiples have values of $A,B,C$ that are unique among $all$ triples. As such, their side ratios are unique unless their respective sides are multiples of each other. Since the big and little triangles in the diagram share the same angle at $C$, they must be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should know which sides are proportional to each other just by looking, because the propotional sides are the opposites at the same corner. So in this case, $\frac{BD}{AE}=\frac{CD}{CA}=\frac{CB}{CE}$.

[this](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/similar-triangles) could be usefull for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about angles. $\angle CBD=180°-90°-\angle ACE=\angle AEC$ so $CD$ is proportional to $AC$.